# Why do my tf-idf values not appear consistent?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, tfidf

I have a series of tweets that I've converted to tokens. Among them are the following:

- geraldkutney happen realize happen conveniently rename catch yet emergency post fact come government
- michaelemann burn happen chickenshittily change get make stupid argument good deed go unpunished
- rickcaughell thomas_6278 coderedearth jrockstrom jordanbpeterson fact exxon predict good accuracy would happen temperature today back 1970s 80 prof model accurate

Note that the first two tweets have 13 total tokens and the  third one has three.

Using the following code, I have created TF-IDF values:

```
vectoriser = sk_text.TfidfVectorizer()

vectoriser.fit(twit_api['text_clean'])

twit_vec = vectoriser.transform(twit_api['text_clean'])
twit_vec.columns = vectoriser.get_feature_names_out()

tokens_enc = twit_vec.toarray()
```

When I look at the tf-idf values for the word 'happen' in each of these, I get values
`0.41124561276932653`, `0.18906439908376366` and `0.1523571031416618`.

This is with the code

```
print(tokens_enc[row_nos[0], vectoriser.vocabulary_['happen']])
```

These values don't appear consistent to me. I would expect the first value to be equal to double the second one as the  tf is exactly double however this doesn't appear to be the case.

Have I misunderstood something?